# correc Input for 2d convolutional layer, given spatial data with labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

So I'm doing a project where I want to train a neural net to assign labels to points in 3d space.

My input is a alpha carbon trace of amino acid, and my labels are it's secondary structure labels, eg. 3 classes.

My data is exactly like:
2945 training examples, each one of length 748, corresponding to 748 consecutive carbons, each one has 3 features that is xyz coordinates.
So X shape is   `(2945, 748, 3)`
and Y shape is `(2945, 748)` as it has 2945 examples, each one has 748 labels for each carbon in sequence.

I want to use specifically convolutional layers, as I've read in a few papers that they are good at spatial dependencies, and would do well on such a problem, it's only that I can't get past dimensions there.

I have expanded dims with: `X_train = np.expand_dims(X_train,1)`
to get `None, 1, 748, 3`
as it is (i think):    `( batch, height, width, channels)`
or do I totally miss the point here?
batch will be specified later,  height is 1, width of example is 748, and channels are 3? as its `xyz`

```
input_shape = (1, 748, 3)
model = Sequential(
[
    Input(shape = input_shape ),
    Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=9, padding='same',
           activation = tf.nn.relu),
    Dense(4, activation='softmax')
]
```

)
model.summary()

summary of model:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 1, 748, 16)        64        
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1, 748, 3)         51        
=================================================================
Total params: 115
Trainable params: 115
Non-trainable params: 0
```

and ofc error:
`ValueError: Shapes (None, 1, 748) and (None, 1, 748, 3) are incompatible`,

I know it would work with 1 unit Dense layer, but if dimensionality is 1, do I still get classification for 3 states?  should be  .

Is my thinking right? or is there a misconception?

I would be very grateful for any word of advice.
Thanks in advance.

Okay,I have one_hot encoded my labels, and expanded dimension one with :

```
np.expand_dims(Y, 1)
```

dimensions achieved:

```
Y train shape: (2356, 1, 748, 4)
Y test shape: (589, 1, 748, 4)
```

what added to Dense with 4 units, matches the dimensions,

Comment: I really don't know whether to upvote or flag this.

Comment: Can you post model.summary() as code, in the same format it is when you run the command

Answer (score 1):

**Working code snippet**

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras import datasets
import tensorflow.keras as keras

X_train = np.random.random((2356,1,748,3))
y_train = np.random.random((2356, 1, 748, 4))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
train_data = dataset.shuffle(len(X_train)).batch(32)
train_data = train_data.prefetch(
        buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

input_shape = (1, 748, 3)
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
[
    keras.Input(shape = input_shape ),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=9, padding='same',
           activation = tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
])

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
```

**Output**

```
Model: "sequential_10"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_10 (Conv2D)          (None, 1, 748, 16)        3904      
                                                                 
 dense_10 (Dense)            (None, 1, 748, 4)         68        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 3,972
Trainable params: 3,972
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/5
472/472 [==============================] - 4s 5ms/step - loss: 3.4528 - accuracy: 0.2508
Epoch 2/5
472/472 [==============================] - 2s 4ms/step - loss: 3.8109 - accuracy: 0.2506
Epoch 3/5
472/472 [==============================] - 2s 5ms/step - loss: 3.8099 - accuracy: 0.2507
Epoch 4/5
472/472 [==============================] - 2s 5ms/step - loss: 3.8021 - accuracy: 0.2506
Epoch 5/5
472/472 [==============================] - 3s 5ms/step - loss: 3.7919 - accuracy: 0.2507
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f55c00dc550>
```